# Window will not appear

Tags: objective-c, xcode, window

I am working on the RaiseMan tutorial and when I run the program in Xcode 4.2.1 the window does not appear. I downloaded the author's solution and ran it and it worked fine so I compared all of my code with his and, to the best of my ability, the info settings and build settings as well as the bindings on the .xib file and cannot find any differences. I ran the author's program again and now it has the same problem. The only thing I can think of is that I have a problem with Xcode or my system. Can anyone give me a hint as to where to look or what to check?

Thanks

I created a new Cocoa Application project, checking 'Create Document-Based Application' and let Xcode 4.2.1 create the appropriate files, etc. The only code I added was NSLog statements to indicate which methods where called. When run, the results were:

> ```
>   autoSavesInPlace
>   autoSavesInPlace
>   autoSavesInPlace
>   windowNibName
>   autoSavesInPlace
>   windowControllerDidLoadNib
>   autoSavesInPlace
>   autoSavesInPlace
>   autoSavesInPlace
>   autoSavesInPlace
> ```

and the default window was displayed. Stopped the app and ran it again with the same results. The third time it was run the result was:

> ```
> autoSavesInPlace
> autoSavesInPlace
> autoSavesInPlace
> ```

and no window was displayed. I have no idea where else to look or how to troubleshoot this problem. Please help.

Comment: What is the RaiseMan tutorial? Are you getting a black screen when you launch the application?

Comment: It's part of the BigNerdRanch book.

Comment: It is a tutorial from 'Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X' by AAron Hillegass and RaiseMan is the first tutorial that uses a document based application. I was sure I had messed something up but when I had the same problem with the author's solution I think I may have other problems. No, I do not get a black screen. Xcode says it is running but there is nothing from the app showing on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The most common error here is unchecking "Show at startup" on the Window object in Interface Builder.

If Xcode is behaving very strangely, and especially if you've upgraded it recently, do reboot. Xcode suggests that you don't need to reboot when you upgrade it, but generally you do (I haven't tested this in recent versions, since I now have a strong habit of always rebooting after upgrading Xcode).

Comment: I had played with "Visible at Launch", have not found "Show at Startup". No luck with my playing. Tried the reboot, computer got hung up part way through the restart. Finally reinstalled Lion, did not cure the problem. Have not tried reinstalling Xcode yet but I guess that is my next step.

Comment: If it is of any help, of the 5 methods that Xcode automatically generates only "autosavesInPlace" gets hit and it is hit 3 times in the first .003 seconds, which means the "windowControllerDidLoadNib" method was not accessed.